# CSS class when focused

Tags: css, focus

I have a class named `.color-blue` with `color:blue !important`.
And I have a class `inputContent` with an input and a div, like this:

```
<div class="inputContent">
   <input>
   <div class="icon color-blue" style="color:red !important;">TEST</div>
</div>
```

and I want on input focused, `.icon` become the color of the class without put `color:blue !important` in inputContent or other.

I have tested

```
.inputContent input:focus ~ .icon {
   color:inherit;
}
```

but nothing.

Comment: In your situation, !important on the inline style will always overrule the !important in the external css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jquery:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(".icon").attr("style", "color:blue");
});
```

Comment: I think that i have found something. remove the inline style from the icon div and use the + sign to create this condition. .icon{
color: red;}
input:focus + .icon{
color: blue;
}

Comment: no exactly. i wrote the correct code one the answer.

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: you have some problem there. see my answer. you have to remove the .color-blue class. instead ,put default color to red on the .icon class. after that add  style to  "input:focus + .icon".

Comment: yeah but I have specifics colors (why I use class, that's more easy) and I use color-lightred etc etc

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 <style>
  .icon{
       color: red;}
       input:focus + .icon{
       color: blue;
      }
</style>  
<div class="inputContent">
<input>
<div class="icon">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 0):

I just want to "remove" or "cancel" the color of `style="color:red !important;"` and replace the color by the class `color-blue` without add lines like `color:blue;`